# Jasmine: How can you return 'x' for call 2 and 'y' for call 3 of a function you're spying on?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'd like to get these specs to pass:

**test.js**

```
var container = {
    method: function () {
        return 'foo';
    },
};

module.exports = container;
```

**testSpec.js**

```
var container = require('../test.js');

beforeAll(function () {
    spyOn(container, 'method').and.returnValues('bar', 'baz');
});

describe('container.method', function () {
    it('first call', function () {
        expect(container.method()).toBe('foo');
    });

    it('second call', function () {
        expect(container.method()).toBe('bar');
    });

    it('third call', function () {
        expect(container.method()).toBe('baz');
    });
});
```

I'd like to do something like `...returnValues({ 'secondCall': 'bar', 'thirdCall': 'baz' });` and have the first call run the original function.

Hardcoding the original's return value isn't DRY and isn't what I want to do (it'd be fine for this test code, but not for more analogous code that is more complex).

Comment: If you're unit testing `container.method`, why spy on it? A spy seems useful for the dependencies _around_ the unit you're testing, not the unit itself.

Comment: @stealththeninja I'm not unit testing `container.method`, I'm just using the unit tests to communicate my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the number of calls by calling `calls.count()`. So to return different values based on the number of calls, you can do this:

```
spyOn(container, 'method').and.callFake(function(){
  var numOfCalls = container.method.calls.count();
  if(numOfCalls === 0)
  {
    return 'foo';
  }
  else if(numberOfCall === 1) {
    return 'bar';
  }
  else {
    return 'baz';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it looks like there's an open issue with Jasmine to allow users to extend spy functionality (think: similar to custom equality testers). From the comments, it looks like it's stalled but also labeled `ready_for_work`.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/720